# How to handle errors during asynchronous response delivery from SMSR back to SMDP/Operator?

Tags: globalplatform

In many scenarios the response with the result of the operation execution is delivered asynchronously to the operation initiator (SMDP or Operator). For example step (13) in 3.3.1 of SGP.02 v4.2:

> (13) The SM-SR SHALL return the response to the “ES3.EnableProfile” function to SM-DP, indicating that the Profile has been enabled

It is not clear how SMSR should act if the call that contains the result of the operation fails. Should SMSR retry such call all the time or it is ok to try just once and give up after that? Does this depend on the type of error that happened during such call?

I'm concerned about the cases when the result is sent and may have been processed by the initiator but the information about that was not properly delivered back to SMSR. In order for SMSR to be required to retry the initiator should be ready to receive the same operation result status again and process it accordingly that is ignore and just acknowledge.

But I can't see anything in the SGP02 v4.2 that specifies what the behaviour of SMSR and SMDP should be in this case. Any pointers to the documentation specifying this are much appreciated.

In general it is not clear how the rollback to a valid know state should happen in this situation. Who is responsible for that (SMSR or SMDP in this example of profile enabling)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any part of the specification defining this. Neither in SGP.02, SGP.01 and the test specification SGP.11. There are operational requirements in the SAS certification for a continuous service. But this is not technically defined.

I have experience in implementing the specification. The approach was a message queue with Kafka and a retry policy. The specification says `SHALL`, which means try very hard. Any implementation dropping the message after a single try is not very quality oriented. The common sense in distributed (micro service) based systems is that there are failures which have to be handled, so this assumption was taken without being expressed in the SGP specification.
The example of the status of a profile should be idempotent, sending a message twice should not be harmful. The `MessageID` and `RelatesTo` is also useful here. I assume for auditing the request / responses are recorded anyway in your system.

In case you are sitting at the other end and are facing a badly implemented SM-SR and nt status message arrives, the ES3.GetEIS can be called by the SM-DP later to get the current status.

I have already contacted the authors directly. At the end of the document the email is mentioned:

> It is our intention to provide a quality product for your use. If you
> find any errors or omissions, please contact us with your comments.
> You may notify us at prd@gsma.com

Comment: This unfortunately does not answer my question. Firstly I'm not asking about _how_ to but _what_ requirements to implement. Secondly I understand options I can choose from in general but my question is about requirements confirming to the specs as I am concerned about interoperability with components from other providers.

Comment: I added a comment how to reach the authors.